# Overlapping delegated DNS zones with possible conflict

Tags: amazon-web-services, google-cloud-platform, dns, overlap

I currently experience a weird behavior regarding one of my DNS delegated zone where A records inside keep having `NXDOMAIN` statuses randomly (or after a while).

My configuration consist of 2 delegated secondary zones in GCP from a primary zone in AWS:

- In AWS Route 53 in my `domain.com` zone:

```
sub.domain.com      NS  ns-cloud-d[1..4].googledomains.com.
dev.sub.domain.com  NS  ns-cloud-b[1..4].googledomains.com.
```

- In GCP Cloud DNS in my `sub.domain.com` zone

```
sub.domain.com      NS  ns-cloud-d[1..4].googledomains.com. (auto-generated)
sub.domain.com      SOA ns-cloud-d1.googledomains.com. cloud-dns-hostmaster.google.com. 1 21600 3600 259200 300 (auto-generated)
app.sub.domain.com  A   x.x.x.x (prod instance IP)
```

- In GCP Cloud DNS in my `dev.sub.domain.com` zone

```
dev.sub.domain.com      NS  ns-cloud-b[1..4].googledomains.com. (auto-generated)
dev.sub.domain.com      SOA ns-cloud-b1.googledomains.com. cloud-dns-hostmaster.google.com. 1 21600 3600 259200 300 (auto-generated)
app.dev.sub.domain.com  A   x.x.x.x (dev instance IP)
```

When trying to reach `app.dev.sub.domain.com` it works for some time and after a while, I got empty `A` record from `dig` with `NXDOMAIN` status.

Another behavior I experience sometimes (not consistently) is different answers from `dig` alternating between good response like this:

```
$ dig app.dev.sub.domain.com @8.8.8.8
[...]
;; ANSWER SECTION:
app.dev.sub.domain.com. 3590 IN A   x.x.x.x (instance IP)
```

and `AUTHORITY` response like that:

```
$ dig app.dev.sub.domain.com @8.8.8.8
[...]
;; AUTHORITY SECTION:
sub.domain.com. 28  IN  SOA ns-cloud-d1.googledomains.com. cloud-dns-hostmaster.google.com. 1 21600 3600 259200 300
```

Even if the 2nd response was bad, I was expecting to see the SOA for `dev.sub.domain.com` and not `sub.domain.com` so I'm wondering if there is some sort of conflict going on in my configuration? And if yes, what possible solutions exist? Very new to DNS setup so any help/advice appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Your question is offtopic here as not related to programming, but in general if you want relevant help you will need to give the real names, not bad obfuscation. Otherwise first try online troubleshooting tools like DNSViz to assess if your zones are correctly resolving. You should also contact your DNS providers for issues on your DNS service. Please see `+trace` option of `dig` also to display full resolution path, and finally "alternating between good response ... and AUTHORITY" is a typical sign of a lame delegation, so check your NS set on both sides of the zone cut.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your Route53 configuration for `dev.sub.domain.com` is wrong. Since you have delegated name servers for `sub.domain.com`, you cannot have another entry for `dev.sub.domain.com`. The lookup for  `dev.sub.domain.com` will happen at `sub.domain.com`. The inconsistent lookup is caused by caching anomalies and client resolver bugs.

Move the `dev.sub.domain.com` record to the DNS servers for `sub.domain.com`.

Comment: Thank you. I wrongly thought it was possible this way. I'll delegate the `dev` zone from the GCP `prod` zone then.